# Windows Creators Update broke my AMD driver - how can I fix it?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, windows-update, amd-radeon

I have an AMD Radeon HD 4800, which I've discovered is technically unsupported on Windows 10 but has worked just fine since I migrated from Windows 7 over a year ago.

Sadly, the "Creator's Update" has today left my display using the Microsoft "Generic" driver with the wrong screen resolution & aspect ratio, and no apparent way to correct it.

AMD's website doesn't have a driver for Windows 10, their [auto-detect tool](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/auto-detect-tool) says the right drivers are already installed, and Windows has greyed out the "Rollback driver" option for my AMD chipset.

Short of rolling back the entire Creator's Update (which would make the already-precarious Windows Update a bit too difficult to navigate on an ongoing basis), how can I get my display back in working order?

Answer (score 6):

It seems that Microsoft or AMD have decided to ship an "update" to the driver, which actually just ends up disabling it. Presumably this is due to its unsupported nature and in order to drive more sales to their newer product lines, despite the fact that the original card is still capable of perfect working order (wasteful, throw-away consumer culture, anyone?!).

Fortunately, you can get it back to that perfect working state, by heading into Device Manager, choosing your chipset, hitting *Update Driver* (I know), then "Browse my computer for driver software", and "let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer".

**The 2017 "update" is listed, as is a 2015 version which is what you want to select and install.**

You then need to download [a tool from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3073930/how-to-temporarily-prevent-a-driver-update-from-reinstalling-in-window) to allow the blocking of specific updates, otherwise you'll be right back where you started within a few days.